# How to get the path to a file in your system

Tags: command-line, files, paths

I am trying to `cd /home/ervin/Downloads/psneuter` in order to push psneuter to an android phone in order to root it. 
I believe the path to the file and folder is correct, yet I get a message no such file or directory. 
Am I doing anything wrong? It worked in Fedora, don't know about here.

Comment: What does `ls -d /home/ervin/Downloads/` say?

Answer (score 1):

Just drag and drop the file in the terminal.

```
         or
```

You can also use the below command to find the path of the file.

find . | egrep filename

Comment: If you're using `find`, why not use its features? You don't need `grep`. The command would be `find ~ -name 'psneuter*' -print`. That assumes that the folder is within the user's home folder; if that assumption is invalid, use `/` instead of `~`.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you 100% sure you got all the capitalization in the directory names correct? Caps matter in unix.
- Or perhaps the files is a psneuter.tar file and you have to untar it first to get the real `psneuter` executable. This is why I never hide file extensions in any GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, and it could be either downloads whit the capital low charter or you could enter in the therimal this:

```
  sudo -i
  cd ~/downloads/psnurther
```

and it might work fine this way.